# Wordpress 2017 full-width template

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, array-difference

I am creating wordpress website and using default 2017 theme.

I've created child theme and created template for full width, but i could't manage to solve this in css file.

I would like to do some css like:

```
.full-width { width: 100%; }
```

and then just apply it

```
<div class="entry-content full-width">
```

but for some reason it never overwrite default style width: 58%

The only way I was able to solve this is to write style straight to the element

```
<div class="entry-content" style="width:100%;">
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this with css class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got a solution by adding a filter in functions.php and it worked for me.

```
function twentyseventeen_body_classes_child( $classes ){
    if( is_page() && is_page_template('full-width.php') ){
        $classes[] = 'page-single-column';
        $classes = array_diff($classes, array('page-two-column'));
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'body_class', 'twentyseventeen_body_classes_child' );
```